# Hankel transform with Bessel functions of the second kind

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

The Hankel transform is defined for Bessel functions of the first kind (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform)

I would like to know if it is possible to define a Hankel transform with Hankel functions, or alternatively with Bessel functions of the second kind.  It seems like a natural extension of the ordinary Hankel transform, but I have not been able to find any good references.

I know these functions are singular at the origin, but because the Hankel function is in some sense a natural construction, it seems like a reasonable thing to consider at least formally.

If this is possible, I would like to know in what cases it is useful, and if there are certain restrictions on the associated function space.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the Bessel function class transforms. A general Google, or Google Scholar, search will yield some results linked to publications.

Hankel transform
\begin{align}
f(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, J_{\nu}(xy) \, \sqrt{xy} \, dx
\end{align}

Y-transform
\begin{align}
f(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, Y_{\nu}(xy) \, \sqrt{xy} \, dx
\end{align}

K-transform
\begin{align}
f(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, K_{\nu}(xy) \, \sqrt{xy} \, dx
\end{align}

Kontorovich-Lebedev transform
\begin{align}
f(y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, K_{i x}(y) \, dx
\end{align}

H-transform
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, {\bf{H}}_{\nu}(xy) \, \sqrt{xy} \, dx
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did find one reference here:  http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0501028?journalCode=sjmaah , which is essentially the Y-transform you mention above.  Also, I did see the Kontorovich-Lebedev transform.  However, I did not find any references on the H-transform as you call it, that seems to have multiple definitions.  I assume H is the Hankel function there.

Comment: I believe the H-transform is actually the inverse of the Y-transform, and the $H_v$ function is actually the Struve function.